# Identify macOS Menu bar app - forking arrows icon

Tags: macos, applications

I follow some videos on macOS and notice this app icon in the Menu bar.

[image]

I am curious to learn more about the app and what purpose it serves. I may possibly be missing a great macOS app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The icon is question is from a paid 3rd party macOS app called [Divvy - Window Manager](https://mizage.com/divvy/).

This app lets you easily and quickly resize app windows into exact portions. The app lets you use keyboard shortcut to present a configurable panel, which can be used to precisely resize window for the frontmost app.

Use keyboard shortcut or click on the app icon in the Menu bar.

[image]

Divvy present the resize panel.

[image]

Click and drag on the boxes to select and resize the app window.

[image]

Divvy is available for download on the Mac App Store:

- [Divvy - Window Manager](https://itunes.apple.com/app/divvy-window-manager/id413857545)

**Note**: No affiliation whatsoever with the developer. Have used the app satisfactorily starting with OS X Yosemite. Using with macOS Mojave as of this writing.